# "ImportError: cannot import name 'chi2' from 'scipy.stats' (unknown location)" when trying to import biogeme

Tags: python, import, error-handling, python-import, importerror

When I check the installation, it looks fine. Not sure what can cause this error. I don't have an environment set up.

Using pip install biogeme, it says requirement fulfilled.
When I import biogeme, I get this exact error:

```
"ImportError: cannot import name 'chi2' from 'scipy.stats' (unknown location)"
```

What should I do?

Comment: What is your python version? Please show full code and error trace back.

Comment: and what's the scipy version?